# Matching htaccess redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I was having a magento site with urls like:-

```
site/page.htm
```

I migrated to wp and want to keep same urls becuase of site ranking and want to redirect all .html to

```
site/page
```

As wp cant add html at the end of the site.

Comment: Yes exactly that would be perfect if I can add .html after every url.

Comment: How do i do it can you tell me

Answer (score 0):

You can add this redirect rule **just below** `RewriteEngine On` rule in site root .htaccess that is being used by wordpress:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html?$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]

# wordpress rules go below this line
```